# How to "teach" a custom command to set rules whilst also using linebreak?

Tags: macros, line-breaking, calculations

So I am sadly still not as versed with TeX as I wish I would be. I am looking for guidance on creating a custom command. I have been doing this manually so far but would want to take a step ahaed.

What I am trying to create is a command that would look something like `\blank{anyword}` which then creates me an underline with 1.5 times the length of the word. That would allow me, when I print that document to have my students fill out the blanks. The only problem I run into now, is that the command as-is is totally ignoring line-breaks and I know no solution to this. After googling like a madman I think there might be none.

I'll post a minimum working example which shows the problem. This is what I currently use, although this might not be the easiest solution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand{\gap}[1]{\rule{\widthof{#1}*\real{1.5}}{0.15mm}}

\begin{document}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    
    anyword
    \vspace*{10mm}\\
    \gap{anyword}
    \vspace*{10mm}\\
    \textbf{Currently:}
    
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam \gap{nonumy-eirmod} tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    \vspace*{10mm}\\
    \textbf{How the Goal looks like:}
    
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam \gap{nonumy} \gap{eirmod} tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
\end{document}
```

Do you have any insight? I would love the code to automatically do the `\rule` command only till the end of `\textwidth` and then make the rest of the gap in the next line of text.

Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In a simple adaptation (see below for better approach), one could make the underline-gap of sub-segments, allowing a break between the sub-segments.  Here, I break the underline-gap into 6 segments.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand{\gap}[1]{%
  \rule{\widthof{#1}*\real{.25}}{0.15mm}\allowbreak%
  \rule{\widthof{#1}*\real{.25}}{0.15mm}\allowbreak%
  \rule{\widthof{#1}*\real{.25}}{0.15mm}\allowbreak%
  \rule{\widthof{#1}*\real{.25}}{0.15mm}\allowbreak%
  \rule{\widthof{#1}*\real{.25}}{0.15mm}\allowbreak%
  \rule{\widthof{#1}*\real{.25}}{0.15mm}%
}

\begin{document}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    
    anyword
    \vspace*{10mm}\\
    \gap{anyword}
    \vspace*{10mm}\\
    \textbf{Currently:}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam \gap{nonumy-eirmod} tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    \vspace*{10mm}\\
    \textbf{How the Goal looks like:}
    
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam \gap{nonumy} \gap{eirmod} tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
\end{document}
```

[image]

**RECOMMENDED APPROACH**

Taking this idea a step further, one could use a token cycle to literally set a rule for each character/space token in the input, which would allow for proper underlining of extended text passages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{calc,tokcycle}
\newcommand{\gap}[1]{%
 \tokencycle
  {\rule{\widthof{##1}*\real{1.5}}{0.15mm}\hspace{0pt minus 2pt}}%
  {\processtoks{##1}}%
  {}%
  {\rule{\widthof{##1}*\real{1.5}}{0.15mm}\hspace{0pt minus 2pt}}%
  #1\endtokencycle
}

\begin{document}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    
    anyword
    \vspace*{10mm}\\
    \gap{anyword}
    \vspace*{10mm}\\
    \textbf{Currently:}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed 
diam \gap{nonumy-eirmod} tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore 
magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed 
diam \gap{nonumy-eirmod nonumy-eirmod nonumy-eirmod nonumy-eirmod
nonumy-eirmod nonumy-eirmod nonumy-eirmod nonumy-eirmod
nonumy-eirmod nonumy-eirmod} tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore 
magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `\gap` command will test whether the material is wider than 3.5em. If it's the case, it produces 1.75em wide rule, then as many copies of a very short rule (3pt) as are necessary to (approximately) fill the requested gap when followed by another 1.75em wide rule.

Between any two short rules a line break is allowed.

If the material is shorter than 3.5em just a non breakable rule is produced.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \replicate \prg_replicate:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newlength{\gaplength}
\newcommand{\gap}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\gaplength}{#1}%
  \ifdim\gaplength<4em
    \leaders\hrule height -2pt depth 2.4pt\hskip\gaplength
  \else
    \splitgap
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\splitgap}{%
  \vrule height -2pt depth 2.4pt width 1.75em
  \replicate{%
    \fpeval{round((\gaplength-3.5em)/(3pt),0)}% how many times
  }{%
    \hbox to 3pt{\hss\vrule height -2pt depth 2.4pt width 3.1pt\hss}\penalty0
  }%
  \unpenalty
  \vrule height -2pt depth 2.4pt width 1.75em\relax
}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, 
sed diam nonumy-eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et 
dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \gap{consetetur} sadipscing elitr, 
sed diam \gap{nonumy-eirmod} tempor invidunt ut labore et 
dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

\end{document}
```

The line breaks are not exactly the same, because the “non-gap” version depends on the hyphenation of the words, which is not possible to take into account in the `\gap` version (well, it would require very substantial work).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to reinvent `dashundergaps`?

With this package there are line breaks in gaps, but words are not hyphenated. However, but with the `teach-mode` you can control easily if some gap need a soft hyphen (`\-`) somewhere.

On the other hand, widening of gaps can be controlled using a larger font plus adding extra width in percentage. This percentage is not unlimited (maximum is around 40% or less, depending largely on the font used for gaps) but as setoff there are others interesting  options.

Example:

---

[image: mwe]

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry,lipsum}\parskip1em % for the mwe only
\usepackage[%
    %%%% teacher-mode=true, % to see hidden text
]{dashundergaps}


\begin{document}
    
\lipsum[1][1-4] % text reference

% Gap without widening nor numbers

{\dashundergapssetup{%
gap-font=\normalsize, % default \bfseries 
gap-widen=false,
gap-number-format={}}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, \gap{vesti\-bulum} ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. \gap{Curabitur  dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer} id, vulputate a, magna.} 

% Default (widening for a bold font and numbers)  

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, \gap{vesti\-bulum} ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. \gap{Curabitur  dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer} id, vulputate a, magna. 

% More widening and styles 

\dashundergapssetup{%
gap-widen=true,
gap-extend-percent=30, % default 20, maximum depends on the gap-font
gap-format=dash, 
gap-number-format= \textsuperscript{\tiny(\thegapnumber)}}    

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, \gap{vesti\-bulum} ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. \gap[.]{Curabitur  dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer} id, vulputate a, magna. 

\dashundergapssetup{%
gap-font=\Huge,
gap-extend-percent=0} % oppss!!decrease it with huge fonts ...


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, \gap[w]{vesti\-bulum} ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. \gap[d]{Cura\-bitur  dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer} id, vulputate a, magna. 


\end{document}
```